# How to deal with reusable use case?

Tags: solid, user-story, use-case, clean-architecture

I'm trying to implement the clean architecture and I'm not sure to quite understand when to reuse interactors (use cases).

Considering that we have one use case such as get user information and we would like to reuse it in different location.

**Screen A**: product owners decided to display very few user information (pictures and name).

**Screen B**: product owners decided to display a lot more user information.

Shall we implement two separated use cases (interactors) or a single one?

What about if product owners decide that for **Screen B** we should not display user information if we don't have all the data retrieved from the API? It will definitely impact **Screen A** and it won't be valid/SOLID anymore.

Comment: Do you mean reusage of a use case diagram, reusage of the written text of a user story, or do you mean reusage of the code which creates the screen content?

Comment: I mean the reusage of the code and specifically the interactor in the case of implementing clean architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my view a "use case" refers to a user, using the product. Not an internal implementation detail such as an internal API.

so you, presumably,  have two use cases

1. as a X I need to see partial data
2. as a Y I need to see full data

Your 2 screens fulfill these requirements, one for each. How they work behind the scenes is up to you

**Example "Use Case"**

> As a "System Admin" I need to view the full details of all "Customers" so that I can do fraud investigations.

**Example "User Story"** (Scrum terminology)

> As a "System Admin" I need to view the full details of all "Customers" so that I can do fraud investigations.

and

> As a "Customer" I need to see my name and address, so i can be sure they are correct.

BUT! importantly this is also a to do list item that you are going to pick up and implement, although it may be divided into smaller tasks.

Normally it would be one to one. But I might have multiple user stories per use case.

**Example Screen**. (Interactor is not a common term)

Web page with a big table of user details.

This might be the result of implementing the user story

**Example service class that the screen uses**

```
public class UserRepo
{
    public List<User> GetAllUsers();
    public List<UserLite> GetUsersWithMinimalDetails();
}
```

Now I can do the sysadmin screen with 'GetAllUsers' and the CustomerDetails screen 
with GetUsersWithMinimalDetails. Or I could use GetAllUsers for both.

I could have two screens, or one, or three. The use use and the user story dont tell me

Comment: Will you have the same approach with different device, such as iPhone and iPad?

Comment: You could choose to combine them or not, eg. " as a user (with a small screen) I want an abbreviated view of X with the details on a second page, so that i can.. blah"

Comment: or simply "as an X I need to see all the details (via an appropriate display) regardless of screen size"

Comment: Having two distincts use cases will defer the responsibility of choosing between the two use cases regarding the screen on a class like a "coordinator". If we have only one Interactor, can it be the responsibility of the Interactor to provide the right amount of data?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand that. The use case or cases describes how the user interacts with the app. So they have no direct affect on the implementation. You could fulfill all the use cases with one dynamic screen and an API which always returns all the data, or you might find it easier to make multiple screens and APIs. either way the use cases are the same.

Comment: I'm sorry if my comment were confused. Let me rephrase it. I completely agree with your solution which is having two use cases. In that case, the object graph is construct regarding the screen size. In my company, product owners are producing only one user story and specify the amount of datas returned regarding screen size in acceptance criteria. Shall we split our user story?

Comment: Or should I build one Interactor that have a different behavior regarding screen size?

Comment: Use cases are not user stories. Developers should not change user stories. I can't comment on the best technical solution to your problem as you have provided no details. All I can say is that the technical solution, whether you make two screens or one, has no bearing on how many use cases or users stories you have and vice versa

Comment: I think I'm going to understand why I'm so confused. I feel I treat user stories like use cases in some case. Do you have any recommendation book/articles/people about user stories/use cases?

Comment: Uncle Bob gave a [talk where he said that use cases and user stories are roughly the same](https://youtu.be/WpkDN78P884?t=866). I thought that one Interactor is associated to one user story.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing too much reading and not enough programming.

Comment: I disagree. It's because I'm doing too much programming and not enough reading that I have question. I tried to implement clean architecture and I'm not an expert. That's why I'm asking here in stack exchange.

Comment: @romsi, Ewan: I get the feeling that you are using the term "use case" to mean different things. Ewan seems to use the term as "a description of how a user interacts with the system" and romsi as "a set of classes with a particular function within the software".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really decide about code reusage when only looking at use case descriptions or user stories: this is typically **the wrong level of abstraction**. At the highest level,  your description says

> "get user information"

which gives the impression this is just two times the same use case. Going more into the details, you see there are differences in Screen A and B, which shows these are two similar use cases, but not exactly the same.

If you switch to the code level, it is often possible to find parts which can be reused, others which cannot. For some, it is probably not immediately clear if the reusage will create some unwanted coupling between screen A and B which might affect future changes.

This is a **judgement call**. Creating reusable components for certain uses cases is not easy. The idea should be to create components following the OCP. So they don't have to be touched in case requirements of one use cases change, and the coupling won't affect other uses cases.

Comment: You right about looking at use case descriptions is the wrong level of abstraction. What will your approach be? Is it correct to say that first start by having to separate components and then refactor it into one if they are similar?

Comment: @romsi: depends on the kind (and size) of system you are building. It makes a large difference if you are building a system with 3 devs, 30 devs or 300 devs. Your overall development plan also matters - if screen A is required now, will B be required next week, next month or next year?

Comment: ... In a small team which has one code base under control, I would try to develop software for one use case using small, reasonable, testable components, and as soon as development for another use case starts, look if those components can be reused (maybe with some refactorings). Refactoring and reusage should go hand in hand. However, one has also to invest some thoughts into the risk induced by coupling, and if those risks are balanced by the benefits of reusage.